# $\sum a_n$ converges iff $\sum \frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

This is a modification of a problem in Rudin.

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of positive numbers (that is $a_n \geq 0)$. Then $\sum a_n$ converges iff $\sum \frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$ converges.

**My attempt**:

$\Rightarrow$ $$\frac{a_n}{1+a_n} \leq a_n$$ and this follows from comparison test.

$\Leftarrow$

Since $$a_n = \frac{a_n}{1+a_n} (1+a_n) = \frac{a_n}{1+a_n} + \frac{a_n^2}{1+a_n}$$

it suffices to show that $\sum \frac{a_n^2}{1+a_n}$ converges. For this, it suffices to show that $(a_n)$ is bounded, because then the result follows from the comparison test. Indeed, let $M$ be an upperbound. Then

$$\frac{a_n^2}{1+a_n} \leq \frac{Ma_n}{1+a_n}$$

We will prove that $a_n \to 0$, and this will prove the boundedness.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Choose $N$ such that $\frac{a_n}{1+a_n} < \frac{\epsilon}{1+ \epsilon}$ for $n \geq N$, which is possible since $\frac{a_n}{1+a_n} \to 0$ since the series converges.

Then, $n \geq N$ implies that $a_n < \epsilon$ and the result follows.

Is this correct? Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof seems fine, maybe for the second implication, we can simply note that, since $a_n \to 0$ eventually $a_n<1$ and then $$\frac{a_n^2}{1+a_n}<\frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$$

As an easier way, assuming that $a_n \to 0$ (otherwise both don't converge), we can use limit comparison test and since

$$\frac{a_n}{\left(\frac{a_n}{1+a_n}\right)}=1+a_n \to 1$$

we conclude that $\sum a_n$ converges $\iff \sum \frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$ converges.

Comment: It is not given that $a_n \to 0$

Comment: @Math_QED If $a_n \not \to 0$ both do not converge.

Comment: Why is it that $\sum a_n/(1+a_n)$ converges $\implies a_n \to 0$ ? Is the reason I gave in my attempt correct?

Comment: @Math_QED The reason is that, assuming $a_n \to 0$, we have $\frac{a_n}{1+a_n}\sim a_n$ therefore you can refer to limit comparison test directly or to the proof of that criteria to show the result.

Comment: @Math_QED Folowing your idea, for the second implication, maybe we can simply note that, since $a_n \to 0$ eventually $a_n<1$ and $$\frac{a_n^2}{1+a_n}<\frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$$

Comment: Yes, that might be easier. But I still don't see how $\sum a_n/(1+a_n) < \infty$ implies that $a_n \to 0$ (Is the proof I provided in my attempt correct?). In your response, you said "assuming $a_n \to 0$", but this is what has to be proven!

Comment: @Math_QED If we assume that $\sum a_n/(1+a_n) < \infty$ it follows that $a_n \to 0$ and thus we can conclude.

Comment: (1) How exactly does it follow? Is it because $a_n/(1+a_n) \to 0 \implies a_n \to 0$? (2) If yes, is my proof of this correct (see my attempt)?

Comment: @Math_QED For (1) try with the three cases $a_n \to 0$, $a_n \to L\neq 0$, $a_n \to \infty$. For (2) from here $\frac{a_n^2}{1+a_n} \leq \frac{Ma_n}{1+a_n}$ you can conclude by comparison test. I don't follow your reasoning at the end.

Comment: But what if the limit doesn't exist (something like $a_n = \sin(n)$)? For example, $\sum |\sin(n)|$ doesn't exist, and $|\sin(n)|$ has no limit. And the reasoning on the end is that I prove $a_n \to 0$ with the definition of limit, given that $\frac{a_n}{1+a_n} \to 0$ (I made small edit).

Comment: @Math_QED If $a_n = \sin n$ (and in general if $a_n \not \to 0$) both series diverges, you can treat that as a special case and then assume as a given that $a_n \to 0$.

Comment: You tell me to consider three cases: but what if $\lim a_n$ doesn't exist? How do I know that $\lim a_n/(1+a_n)$ doesn't exist either?

Comment: @Math_QED I tell that in order to convince yourself that $a_n/(a_n+1) \to 0 \iff a_n \to 0$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80684/discussion-between-math-qed-and-gimusi).

Comment: If $b_n = \frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$ then $a_n = \frac{b_n}{1-b_n}$; so $b_n \to 0$ implies $a_n \to 0$.

Comment: Nice comment thanks. @gimusi provided another excellent way in the chat.

Answer (score 2):

**Claim.** If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$ converges then $a_n\to 0$.

[If I understood correctly, this was the only subtle point. The rest of your proof was perfectly clear].

**Proof of the claim.** If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$ converges, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1+a_n}{1+a_n}-\frac{1}{1+a_n}\right)$ converges, so $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(1-\frac{1}{1+a_n}\right)$ converges. By the $n$-th term test, the sequence $1-\frac{1}{1+a_n}$ must converge to $0$. Thus, $\frac{1}{1+a_n}\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$. From here it is easy to see that $1+a_n \to 1$ and so $a_n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$ converges.

We claim that $a_n \to 0$. Let $0 < \varepsilon < 1$ and pick $n_0 \in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n \ge n_0 \implies a_n < \frac{\varepsilon}{1-\varepsilon}$. For such $n$ we have

$$a_n < \frac{\varepsilon}{1-\varepsilon} \iff a_n(1-\varepsilon) < \varepsilon \iff a_n < \varepsilon (1+a_n) \iff \frac{a_n}{1+a_n} < \varepsilon$$

Now pick $M > 0$ such that $1+a_n \le M, \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.

We have

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{Ma_n}{1+a_n}$$

which converges so $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ also converges by the comparison test.

Comment: Thanks. I think there is an issue in your proof if $\epsilon \geq 1$.

Comment: @Math_QED True, just assume $0 < \varepsilon < 1$ so that $\frac{\varepsilon}{1-\varepsilon} > 0$.